# Elegant way to concat all dict values together with a string carrier as a single string in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

The objective is to `concat` all values in a `dict` into a single `str.`

Additionally, the `\r\n` also will be appended.

The code below demonstrates the end result.

However, I am looking for a more elegant alternative than the proposed code below.

```
d=dict(idx='1',sat='so',sox=[['x1: y3'],['x2: y1'],['x3: y3']],mul_sol='my love so')

s=''
for x in d:
    if x=='sox':
        for kk in d[x]:
            s=s +kk[0] +'\r\n'
    else:

        s=s +d[x]+'\r\n'
print(s)
```

Comment: You may find codereview.stackexchange.com a place better suited to this

Comment: Not quite - code review will tell give you opinions on aspects of the code, but it's off-topic to ask for a rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two generators, one for `d['sox']` and another for everything else, and then use `join()` to concatenate strings.

```
s = ''.join(kk[0] for kk in d['sox']) + '\r\n'
s += '\r\n'.join(val for key, val in d.items() if key != 'sox')
```

Comment: Sorry, left out the call to `.items()`

Comment: You missed out the final CRLF.

Comment: And changed the order of the output.

Comment: @TobySpeight Dictionary order is usually not significant.

Comment: It's easy to add another CRLF if needed.

Answer (score 2):

following code have more control over what might have in the dictionary:

```
def conca(li):
  ret=''
  for ele in li:
    if isinstance(ele,str):
        ret += ele + '\r\n'
    else:
        ret += conca(ele) 
  return ret

print(conca([d[e] for e in list(d)]))
```

or if want a more versatile solution:

```
def conca(li):
 ret = ''
 for ele in li:
    if isinstance(ele, str):
        ret += ele + '\r\n'
    elif isinstance(ele, list):
        ret += conca(ele)
    elif isinstance(ele, dict):
        ret += conca(ele.values())
    # you can add any other customized conversions here...
    else:
        raise Exception(
            "value of dictionary can only be str, list or dict~")
 return ret
print(conca([d[e] for e in list(d)]))
```

Comment: I like your recursive solutions; for the 2nd one you could make it even more versatile (and slightly more compact) with:     elif type(ele) in {dict, list, tuple}:  ret += conca(list(ele)) ; btw, there's an unwelcome indent in your last 'print' line.

Comment: @Swifty thanks for the tips, i fix the indent.  there is a error in previous answer, i should use `ele.values()`, instead of `list(ele)`(this actually depends on what the user of this code want to convert to str..), so i can't combine all the types in one elif statement...

Comment: Oh indeed, I didn't try it with a dict, but you're right of course. You could still add tuple treatment, but as you say, depends on what one wants :)

Answer (score 2):

Make a separate function that transforms the values, and then apply that using `map`.

```
d = {
    'idx': '1',
    'sat': 'so',
    'sox': [['x1: y3'],['x2: y1'],['x3: y3']],
    'mul_sol': 'my love so'
}

crlf = '\r\n'

import operator

def transform_sox(item):
    (key, val) = item
    if key == 'sox':
        return crlf.join(map(operator.itemgetter(0), val))
    else:
        return val

print(crlf.join(map(transform_sox, d.items())), crlf)
```

Not necessarily shorter, but clearer and more maintainable in my opinion.

---

Alternatively, if we can rely on the value *type* to determine the transformation, rather than the key:

```
def transform_sox(value):
    return value if isinstance(value, str) \
        else crlf.join(map(operator.itemgetter(0), value))

print(crlf.join(map(transform_sox, d.values())), crlf)
```

---

In the other direction, perhaps you need custom formatters for a few elements in the dictionary.  In which case, look up the formatter for each element:

```
formatters = collections.defaultdict(lambda: lambda x: x)
formatters['sox'] = lambda x: crlf.join(map(operator.itemgetter(0), x))

def transform_sox(item):
    return formatters[item[0]](item[1])

print(crlf.join(map(transform_sox, d.items())), crlf)
```